# why don't large magents repel themselves

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

This question may have been asked before so I apologize in advance if it has.  I've been playing with some magnetic buckyballs I got recently (highly recommend getting some if you dont have any) and have had one question about magnetism I haven't been able to figure out.

I understand how N is attracted to S and N will repel N.  What I'm wondering is what prevents a large magnet from repelling itself.

Hypothetically you have a magnet that looks like this

[N][S]

and it makes sense that the N stays connected with the S, but what if you have a bigger magnet

[N][N][N][N][S][S][S][S]

what prevents the first two [N] or the last two [S] from repelling one another?  Is it just that the force from the other side carries all the way through?  Does this mean there is an upper limit to magnet size?

Comment: Hi Ben. In a fit of creativity I have added what I hope are helpful images. If you don't like them please roll back my edit, or comment here and I'll back it out.

Comment: @JohnRenni The second picture does not properly replace the ascii art. (And you cannot replace it, unless you draw magnetic monopoles in a large magnet).

Comment: @SebastianRiese: let's see what Ben thinks.

Comment: The second picture got the point across to me really well.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I second Sebastian's thoughts; I think OP intended to draw a single magnet with segmenting each half (N,S) into multiple parts.

Comment: Well edit in your own image then instead of kibitzing!!

Comment: @JohnRennie: I'd rather wait for OP to respond before attempting that, just stating my two cents on it

Comment: Maybe my conceptual understanding of magnets is flawed... but if you take any large magnet I am thinking you'll have molecules arranged like:
  
NNNNN
SSSSS

So I'm wondering what happens to the molecules in the outer layer furthest from the center

Comment: See my answer. The individual components are unpaired electrons not molecules, and they're aligned NS-NS-NS-NS with each individual NS being the magnet dipole of one electron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large magnet is indeed made up of lots of tiny magnets. In fact every unpaired electron in the material acts as a tiny bar magnet and the total field is made up by summing the individual magnetic fields of all these gazillions of electrons.

You are quite correct that if you place two bar magnets alongside each other with the north poles together then they will repel each other. This happens in most materials that have unpaired electrons and these materials are described as [paramagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism). They have no overall magnetic fields precisely because the electrons won't align their magnetic fields.

The sort of materials that you and I normally think of as *magnetic* are described as [ferromagnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism). In ferromagnets there is an extra interaction called an [exchange force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Exchange_interaction) that overcomes the repulsion between the individual electron magnetic moments and allows them to align with each other. When this happens the individual magnetic fields reinforce each other and we get the macroscopic magnetic fields that we normally think of as *magnets*.

Comment: ok this makes more sense.  And especially your comment above about ns-ns-ns-ns creating a net effect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The story about designed permanent magnets starts with the creation of such magnets. One take materials - often including rare earth materials - with hight magnetic dipole moments and make a powder from this material. Before starting to [sinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintering) this material it will be switched on a strong magnetic field that aligns the before chaotic distributed magnetic dipole moments. One transfer energy into this alignment. Therefore the sintered magnetic is under inner tensions.

This one can see easy by dropping the magnet on the floor. Don't do this or be very careful in the case of strong magnets! So the unpaired electrons are aligned in a "chain" north-south-north-south-.... but the molecules are not in equilibration.